# How to enable configuration validation for AutoMapper and throw an exception at compile time?

Tags: c#, automapper

When I use the two-parameter Map function to map objects of the same type, the target object is not mapped successfully. The reason is that I did not add the mapping rule in the profile. To prevent this kind of error in use, I want to find a way to point out the error at compile time, Is there such a way?

I tried using dependency injection, but there is no way to detect it at compile time.

Comment: Nope, there is no way to make it detect al the compile time. The list of types are loaded at the run time from the Profile and only when you have to use a type it will be detected as missing from the list.

Comment: Without any code you're asking people to guess but I suspect the real problem is the *misuse* of AutoMapper. AutoMapper is meant to map objects by *convention*. You should really read [AutoMapper's design philosophy](https://www.jimmybogard.com/automappers-design-philosophy/) : `AutoMapper works because it enforces a convention. It assumes that your destination types are a subset of the source type... everything on your destination type is meant to be mapped... the destination member names follow the exact name of the source type ... you want to flatten complex models into simple ones.`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [AutoMapper AssertConfiguration at compile time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2061316/automapper-assertconfiguration-at-compile-time)

Comment: In any case, it's not possible to validate at compile time. The unconventional mappings are added at *runtime*, not compile-time. You can verify a configuration at runtime by using [configuration.AssertConfigurationIsValid](https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Configuration-validation.html#configuration-validation). You could create a Roslyn analyzer to do that at compile time, provided you find a way to run the custom configuration code in the analyzer.

Comment: As Jimmy Bogard, the creator of AutoMapper, says in the duplicate, the best place to verify is the unit tests, not compilation. He's the same guy that wrote the `AutoMapper Philosophy` article